# Deployed app throwing 404 errors on refresh

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I've just deployed my first Ember-cli app, it's not finished, but I want to show it to the other contributor. 
It works fine on my localhost, in development. 
Now that I've deployed it to the server, it throws a 404 error when the 'refresh' button is pressed in the browser. Following links works just fine, but trying to navigate directly to a URL throws a 404 error.

I've implemented location: 'auto' in my router, which should use history or hash, whichever the browser supports.

It's deployed at www.merit.bromine001.com

Comment: What http server are you using?  Apache?  nginx?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't just your browser that needs to support it, your web server needs to be implemented in such a way that anything after the `rootUrl` is ignored, and the ember app is served.

If you don't want to implement it server side, or want to punt, just change the location to hash.